# is it possible to create an HTML FORM from wtform implementation?

Tags: wtforms

is it possible to automatically generate an html form from the wtform itself?

so if i have:

```
class baseform(Form):
    name = StringField('name')
    weight = IntegerField("weight")
```

i would like to automatically generate the HTML for that form:

```
<form>
<input id="name" ...>
<input id="weight" ...>
</form>
```

is it possible?

thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 0):

From the [WTForms documentation](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.__iter__), you can iterate over the form:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ field.label }}</th>
        <td>{{ field }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If that's too much typing, you can always create a macro in your template language of choice.

Comment: it is fine but it just doesn't work for me...
i Get: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
on: <td>{{ field }}</td>

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, it was related to a custom field that we used in the "real" form.. the custom field inherited from Field that didn't had the **call** implementation, so we changed the inheritance to be from StringField instead (we could also implement the **call** ourselves, but StringField is good enough for our needs)

Thanks.